# Elasticsearch - regex search

Tags: elasticsearch

I created document with some string as text.

```
test_index/_doc
{"D" : "A1#A2#A3!A4#A5#A6"}
```

and I tried to query to find this document like below.

```
// able to find the document
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "D": ".*a1.*"
    }
  }
}

// cannot find the document with below queries.
    {
      "query": {
        "regexp": {
          "D": ".*a1#.*"
        }
      }
    }
    {
      "query": {
        "regexp": {
          "D": ".*\"a1#\".*"
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried to change '#' symbol to others such as '!', '@' but still same query result.
WHY am i unable to find document with second way? and how should i do to find the document with specific char.

Comment: Are you certain that what you reported above is reproducible?  I would not expect it.

Comment: why do you think that way. I can still do same test with this queries. using ES 6.2 version.